# Is there an abstract algebraic way to analyze the rational numbers between 0 and 1 (inclusive)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, fractions

I'm wondering if the rationals between $0$ and $1$, have been studied in a systematic manner using abstract algebra.

Is there any interesting theory behind this set?

Comment: Way to vague. What properties do you want to study?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is one of the most frequent sources of counterexamples to show that statements about f.g. $R$-modules don't extend to all $R$-modules.

Comment: I think you want something relating algebraic numbers. You can search for the Liouville number.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. Well... I did not have anything specific in mind. I thought just as the rational numbers are the archetypal "field"... It seemed to me that the numbers 0->1 must have some deep algebraic important algebraic structure. Just a guess. I think user73985 has given me something to study.

Comment: @AmeetSharma What *kind* of algebraic structure are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lattice theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_theory) is studied algebraically, and this is a natural example of a bounded totally ordered lattice, so I would say "yes."

If you are thinking explicitly of some operation induced by that of $\Bbb Q$, I can think of no better suggestion than what user73985 has already offered with $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$. The rationals in $[0,1)$ act as coset representatives. Although $1$ and $0$ overlap here, it's still an excellent suggestion.